# MySQL 5.7 using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not working

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table existed. I want to alter the table so that it has a column storing Created date. I had looked up some articles insists that from Mysql ver 5.6, you can use DATETIME with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. but I failed to implement.

```
~:$  mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for macos10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

MYSQL VERSION 5.7

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY datecreated DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1
```

error occured

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default                 | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL                    | auto_increment |

...
...
..
.
.
.
| datecreated   | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL                    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

table infos.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY datecreated DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: Just to make it clear what @fifonik was pointing out, you still need to declare the column type (`DATETIME`) in your `MODIFY` clause

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, and especially @fifonik and @NICK

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY datecreated DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Thanks I was using DataGrip and modify table sets it to 'alter column' and modify fixed it for me